# Relation of pressure and temperature for an ideal gas at constant volume

Tags: gas-laws, units

I have a tank of ideal gas with volume $3.1\ \mathrm L$; I have $R = 8.314$, and 11 moles. The tank is filled at $23\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ (not sure why that's relevant) and the tank will rupture at $P = 100\ \mathrm{atm} = 1.013\cdot 10^7\ \mathrm{Pa}$. At what temperature does the tank rupture?

I divided $PV$ by $nR$. However, plugging those numbers in gives

$$\frac{3.1 \times 1.013\times 10^7}{8.314\times 11} = 342374$$
in kelvin. However, my book gives $70.2\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ as the correct answer. I assume my units are somehow profoundly messed up. Or maybe that mysterious 23 has something to do with it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Our units of volume are $m^3$, not $L$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the value of $R=8.314$, the units are $\mathrm{\frac{J}{K\cdot mol}}$. One [joule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) is equal to:

$$\mathrm{J=\dfrac{kg\cdot m^2}{s^2}=N\cdot m = Pa\cdot m^3 = W\cdot s = C\cdot V}$$

If you want to use volume in liters, you need to use a different value for R.

Answer (score 6):

> The tank is filled at 23 °C (not sure why that's relevant).

This information is crucial :)

For the initial situation, the number of moles, the volume and the temperature are given.

$$P\,V = n\,\mathrm{R}\,T$$

Plugging these into the ideal gas equation will give you the **initial pressure**.

Given that the number of moles and the volume don't change, increasing the temperature will raise the pressure until the tank eventually bursts.

Just remember *Gay-Lussac's* law:

$\Large{\frac{P_1}{T_1} = \frac{P_2}{T_2}}$

Comment: Hmm... Why can't I just plug into the ideal gas law at 100 atm? There would only be 1 unknown.

Comment: @RenéG You certainly can. I thought that mentioning the underlying, older law might help.